# Jquery mobile link to local file

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I have following code in `index.html`:

```
<a data-ajax="false" rel="external" href="../Info/BasicDefinition.pdf"
 data-theme="c" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="arrow-d" data-role="button">Structure</a>
```

But i get 404 error - file not found after click on `structure` link. What i must change? I want to open .pdf file from browser.
My file structure (MPSR - root folder of my web site)

```
-MPSR
-----index.html
-Info
-----BasicDefinition.pdf
```

Comment: So the Info folder is outside your web site root folder? If so, you can't access the file.

Comment: without jquery i can access!

Comment: I can't see any jQuery on your code. Or your web site root folder is not actually MPSR. It's impossible to access folders out of the root one, unless you have virtual folders set on IIS.

Comment: steps: 1) create folder Test; 2)Create into folder Test new folder MPSR; 3)Into folder MPSR create file index.html with following code:

Comment: <html><head></head><body><a href="../BasicDefinition.pdf">Link</a></body></html> 4) put into test pdf file BasicDefinition.pdf 4)Open index.html and click Link -> pdf will opens

Comment: So, actually, your web site root folder is Test. MPSR is a sub folder, which contains the `index.html` file.

Comment: And it looks like you're testing this just locally. I was talking about proper deployment (using a server).

Comment: It's example. Really i have two folders: Info with pdf files and MPSR with index.html and some jquery files. I want open pdf files from index.html

Comment: I got it. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linking without Ajax**

*Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false") have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external" should be used when linking to another site or domain, while data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions, the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax behavior.*

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

So, you can remove the `rel="external"` from your tag and it should work.

I can't post this on jsFiddle, as it wouldn't work, but I've tested here and it worked fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title>       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page"> 
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Page Title</h1>
            </div> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <a data-ajax="false" href="../info/test.txt" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="arrow-d" data-role="button">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div> 
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Folder structure:

```
\test
    \info
        \test.txt
    \root
        \index.html
```

Comment: but i try it. doesn't wotk (

Comment: Updated the answer with a test.

Comment: I don't now, but i do not work! link looks .....\MPSR\info\test.txt. Not go up on a tree =(

Comment: If you copy this piece of code and save it on the same file structure, you'll see it working. And it's just a replica of your post, apart from the fact that I named a folder `root` (which doesn't change anything) and I'm linking to a text file because I don't have any PDF here.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Tested on Chrome, Firefox, IE (7,8,9 and 10).

Comment: Please, send on my email archive with your project (isxaker@gmail.com)

Comment: That's what I meant with a "real server". The Visual Studio will work just like if you've published the project on IIS. Once you define the root folder, you can't access files outside of it.

Comment: In my project, there is no real server. All will be locally! Thank's a lot!